$\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ as a union of $F_\sigma$ set and a set of measure zero
Every measurable set in a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact, Hausdorff space $X$, under a suitably nice regular measure, is the union of an $F_\sigma$ and a set of measure zero; this is well-known. However, I am struggling to see how one can write $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ (under the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$) as such a union- is there a known such construction? I'm stuck on where to begin. This is certainly a measurable set; $\mathbb R$ is $\sigma$-compact and Hausdorff; and the Lebesgue measure can be obtained via the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem, and is hence "nice" enough, so certainly this is possible, but I can't think of a suitable measure zero subset of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ to remove, or conversely of a suitable $F_\sigma$ to remove.

Take a $G_\delta$ null set $K$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} = (\mathbb{R} \setminus K) \cup (K \setminus \mathbb{Q})$ is a union of an $F_\sigma$ set and a null set.
To construct such a $K$, take an enumeration $\{q_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then let $K_m = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} (q_n - \frac{2^{-n-1}}{m}, q_n + \frac{2^{-n-1}}{m})$. Then $\lambda(K_m) \leq \frac{1}{m} \to 0$, $K_m$ is open, and $\mathbb{Q} \subset K_m$ for all $m$, so $K = \bigcap_{m \geq 1} K_m$ satisfies the desired conditions.

This is a good example to know.  Also, to understand that $K \ne \mathbb Q$.

@GEdgar Indeed, $K = \mathbb{Q}$ seems a common misperception.
